# Sublime Text 3 Run Command on Multiple Files

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I'm using the CodeFormatter package with Sublime Text 3 on OSX Yosemite to tidy up my PHP code.

Is there a way to run a command from a package on a whole directory of files at one go?

I saw the Build Systems but it doesn't really give enough details to understand if it would do this or not. It mostly talks about external commands.

I know ST3 also has a command line interface, might it be possible from there?

Comment: Sounds like a question to http://superuser.com?

Comment: Not if there's a programmatical way to get it done.